# Assigning unique Values to adjacent raster cells

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have a raster file like the one below. All green cells have the same value. The white space between the green cells is no data. I want to combine adjacent raster cells to one "count" and give them a unique value. Is this possible?  I´m using ArcMap.

[image: Rasterfile]

This is what I want to do:
[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [Region Group](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/region-group.htm) (requires Spatial Analyst):

> For each cell in the output, the identity of the connected region to
>   which that cell belongs is recorded. A unique number is assigned to
>   each region.

Comment: Thanks, Region Group  works perfectly even for corner connected cells, you just have to set "number of neighbours to use" to "EIGHT" and it will concider all possible neighbour cells.